# reading from excel using Java poi 4.11

Tags: java, apache-poi, excel-2007

Why it outputs an error"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (0) is out of range (no sheets)"

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class test {
    public static void  main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/KP/IdeaProjects/JavaExcel/read.xls");


        String result = wb.getSheetAt(1).getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

        System.out.println(result);
        fis.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you did not load your inputstream into the workbook. You need new HSSFWorkbook(fis);

Answer (score 0):

You created a new Workbook and access the sheet at Index 1.

If you want to load your Inputstream to your workbook you need to create a new Workbook with the InputStream.

You should also use try with resources to close your stream and workbook.

```
try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/KP/IdeaProjects/JavaExcel/read.xls"); 
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(in)) {

    String result = wb.getSheetAt(1).getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Please notice that `getSheetAt(1)` returns the **second** sheet. If you want the first sheet you need to use `getSheetAt(0)`. Same goes for `getRow` and `getCell`. So if you want the first cell in the first row in the first workbook use:

```
String result = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. If I understood you correctly, then:
```import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
public class test {
    public static void  main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/KP/IdeaProjects/JavaExcel/read.xls");
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(in)) {
String result = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
System.out.println(result);}}}```

Comment: But there were new errors 
.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/math3/util/ArithmeticUtils"
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.commons.math3.util.ArithmeticUtils

Comment: @Альберт: It lacks prerequisites. In that case it lacks `commons-math`. See https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components. If you get `ClassNotFoundException` then internet-search about the mentioned class name to get what library contains it.

Answer (score 0):

declare/ Initialize the workbook after file input stream like below by passing fis object

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/KP/IdeaProjects/JavaExcel/read.xls");
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);

hope you have data in the second sheet of excel file as mentioned "wb.getSheetAt(1)", if not make it  wb.getSheetAt(0)